# CloudPages subdomain

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Is there any way to drop the 'cloud' from a cloudpage URL?

Right now it's `cloud.domainname.com/funstuff` is there a way to either mask the `cloud` or an account setting that can nix it all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't possible to turn off or get rid of the subdomain used for Cloud Pages, but you can change it to be something other than 'cloud'. If the domain is delegated to SFMC then you can open a support ticket to have the deliverability team make the change to whatever you want to use as the subdomain name.